# Form Submissions Overwriting Existing Contacts

Tags: webform-civicrm

Our form is overwriting existing contacts when a new submission is made.

All of our dedup rules are related to same names and emails; I do not see any dedup rule that would overwrite a (seemingly random) contact record with a new contact's information.

How can I prevent this in the future?

This issue began with [my question here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/33851/what-would-cause-contributions-and-contacts-to-go-missing).The suggestion was excellent, and helped me get to a better understanding of what happened. But I'm still missing precisely where the overwrite is happening. (To be fair, the full suggestion is to check the logs, but I lack the ability to write a query that pinpoints what I want to understand)

Comment: for checking the logs try the log viewer extension: https://github.com/adixon/ca.civicrm.logviewer

Comment: Can you be more specific about the form? Is it a Drupal webform, a profile form, a contribution form? Each of those has it's own configuration for how to handle potential duplicates.

Comment: Are the forms being submitted by logged-in users, or 'anonymously'? If by logged-in users, see this extension - https://civicrm.org/extensions/no-overwrite

Comment: thanks to all. @petednz - I am checking the logs, thanks.

Comment: @AlanDixon it's a drupal form with civi webform integration

Comment: @JoeMcLaughlin anonymous users overwrite existing contacts, so in this case the ext would not work. but thank you, because I have definitely encountered this in other situations.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input. It was a very odd matching rule, one that matched on last name with length one, weight one. I will see this was added to the site.

Comment: I will see *when* this was added to the site

Comment: Cool Laurynn glad you figured it out

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for everyone's input. It was a very odd matching rule, one that matched on last name with length = 1, weight = 1. I will see when this was added to the site.

Comment: Ouch. Ouch. Ouch (x3 to get over the minimum 10 characters for a comment!)

Answer (score 0):

What is your Matching Rule in the Webform configured at? This is where you find that:

[image]

Next -> post a screenshot of that Rule (in your CiviCRM config) as well as a Screenshot of your Webform tab (showing all the elements on the form as well as their Form_keys